# Where clause with a blank variable Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, where-clause

I use GET, to collect a variable :

```
$subid = $_GET['subid'];
```

In my DB Query i have the following :

```
->where('subID', '=', $subid)
```

Now if the variable $subid is blank , the result returns no information. How do i specify in the query that if the variable $subid is blank or empty, return all results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `when`.

```
->when($subid, function ($query) use ($subid) {
    return $query->where('subID', '=', $subid);
})
```

If $subid is false the where condition won't be applied to the query.

Check out the doc https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#conditional-statements

**UPDATE:**

Any expression that you can be used inside an `if` call can be used as the first argument of `when`

An example :

```
->when($fromDate && $toDate, function($query) use ($fromDate, $toDate) {
    return $query->whereBetween('CompletedDate', array($fromDate, $toDate));
})
```

Comment: what if the where query is a whereBetween Query.  ->whereBetween('CompletedDate', array($fromDate, $toDate)). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [orWhere()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses):

```
->where('subID', '=', $subid)
->orWhere('subID', '=', '');
```